# PySpark replace values below count threshold with values

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to replace all values with occurence lower than set threshold with another value - Spark 2.1.0 , PySpark API and using DataFrame.

When I test the function on an example (`df1` below), it works. But not on my real data. Both have the `dtype` attribute - string. With `df1`, I run the columns 'cat' and 'integers' in a for loop, which is what I want with the real data DF as well and again it works perfectly.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "a","1"),
    (1, "b","1"),
    (2, "c","1"),
    (3, "a","1"),
    (4, "a","2"),
    (5, "c","2"),
    (6,"b","1"),
    (7,"b","1"),
], ["id", "cat","integer"])

def cutoff(df,feat,threshold, otherclass='other'):
    if isinstance(threshold, float) and threshold<1:
        threshold = str(int(threshold*df.count()))

    if isinstance(threshold,int):
        threshold = str(threshold)

    temp = df.groupBy(feat).count().orderBy('count')
    replace = temp.filter("count<"+threshold).select(feat).rdd.map(lambda r:r[0]).collect()
    print "replacing ", replace,replace.__class__, " with ", otherclass, " subset ", feat
    df = df.replace(replace,otherclass,feat)

    return df
```

But when using real data (SQL import from Hive), I obtain

```
mydata (just a part):
+---------------+-----+
|   browser_name|count|
+---------------+-----+
|         Chrome| 2197|
|             IE|  719|
|        Firefox|  542|
|  Mobile Safari|  370|
|Android Browser|  361|
|           Edge|  265|
| Chrome WebView|  203|

replacing  [u'Iron', u'UCBrowser', u'Puffin', u'Opera Mini', u'Yandex', u'Maxthon', u'Silk', u'Vivaldi', None, u'MIUI Browser', u'Chromium', u'WebKit', u'IEMobile', u'Facebook', u'Chrome WebView', u'Safari', u'Opera', u'Android Browser', u'Mobile Safari', u'Edge', u'IE', u'Firefox'] <type 'list'>  with  other  subset  browser_name


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1704248642413819893.py", line 267, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1704248642413819893.py", line 265, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in cutoff
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1345, in replace
    self._jdf.na().replace(self._jseq(subset), self._jmap(rep_dict)), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4471.replace.
: scala.MatchError: null
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.replace0(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.replace(DataFrameNaFunctions.scala:336)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor359.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So it complains about the `replace` function. But when I only run 
`df.replace(['Chrome','Firefox'],'hovno','browser_name').show(10)` it works like a charm again (I even tried to input the list in unicode as the function generates it and its ok). So I'm wondering what did I do my `DF` in the function that it doesn't work? I understand `MatchError` as not being able to find the source values to replace, but they are surely there.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my dataframe contains None values which the `replace` cannot match. As a workaround I use `fillna` first which replaces None values with something and then it works like a charm.